# How to match multiple paths with similar names in nginx?

Tags: nginx

I got the following URL patterns in nginx but I was able to hit the URL `/chat` and not `/chat-test`

```
 location /chat {
     proxy_pass http://localhost:8080
 }

 location = /chat-test {
     proxy_pass http://localhost:8081
 }
```

I tried few solutions but none worked and the `response was 404` `- Page not found`.  However, I am able to curl the backend service

I am not sure what am I doing wrong.  The only thing what I suspect is `nginx version 1.14.1`

Kindly let me know had anyone faced similar issue

**EDIT**

**access log**

```
10.xx.xxx.xx - - [11/Feb/2022:01:29:42 -0500] "GET /chat-test HTTP/2.0" 404 148 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/98.0.4758.82 Safari/537.36"
```

**CURL output**

```
[root@nginx]# curl 10.xxx.xx.xx:8081
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Error</title>
</head>
<body>
<pre>Cannot GET /</pre>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The configuration you have should work. Please share the error.log or access.log as well as the curl command you are using for `/chat` and `/chat-test`.

Comment: @TimoStark Updated with the required information

Comment: In your example you are not sending `/chat-test` to your backend. just `/`. What the output of `curl -v 10.....:8081/chat-test`? Remember, NGINX will pass the `request_uri` to the proxy server. So make sure `/chat-test` exists. if you DON'T want this, use a rewrite to remove it.